# Tweets in my Tweetbot timeline are occasionally marked as a favorite when I see them for the first time. Is that a bug or a feature?

Tags: twitter, bug, tweetbot

While looking through my timeline in [Tweetbot](http://tapbots.com/software/tweetbot/), occasionally a tweet will be marked as a favorite even though I'm sure I'm seeing it for the first time.  (I can't resist taking the time to *unfavorite* it.)  I don't see any mention of this in http://tapbots.com/support/tweetbot/.  Is this a bug, or a "feature" (where perhaps Twitter's API is doing this)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug with Twitter, not Tweetbot.

I've seen people ask [@tweetbot](https://twitter.com/#!/tweetbot) about it several times now. The answer and response generally look [like this exchange](https://twitter.com/#!/tweetbot/status/129718654764986368):

> Q: @tweetbot keeps favoriting random tweets in my timeline. It's almost embarrassing.
>
> A: Sorry, that's a Twitter bug. As you can see on Favstar, they're not real favorites.

That particular exchange happened just yesterday.

[Twitter's REST API bug list has this bug still open](https://dev.twitter.com/issues/4) where the API may erroneously report a tweet as favorited when in fact it is not.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this happen in the official Twitter app, so it might be a bug in the Twitter API.